# suck at judging our smarts

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "suck at judging our smarts" mean "are incompetent at judging our own intelligence"?

> Why we’re in tune with our emotions – but **suck at judging our smarts**
> “Know thyself” is a piece of wisdom handed down from the ancients – but a slew of delusions and biases means you might be better off asking someone else

> Read more: https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg24833122-000-why-were-in-tune-with-our-emotions-but-suck-at-judging-our-smarts/#ixzz6iOvkRDlS

Comment: It's *extremely* slangy (and would normally include emphatic ***own*** before ***smarts***), but yes - that's what it would mean. The cited writer is being deliberately "quirky"  by using such a "low register" slang expression in the context of an article that's heavily loaded with "high register" usages (***quixotic, delusional, chivalry***,... are all "50-cent" words compared to dime-a-dozen slang usages like that one in the article title - which to some extent could be described as "click-bait").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Suck at* means being bad at something. *Smarts* is similar to *intelligence*, but it carries more of a sense of being able to understand and judge things well, making quick decisions, not being easily fooled etc. Often people who are *academically intelligent* aren't especially *street smart*.

Those are kind of arbitrary concepts anyway, but *smarts* is a more general and less formal way of talking about people's ability to understand the things around them, and navigate their lives. So what the quote is saying is "we're not very good at judging our own knowledge and ability to understand things and the situations we're in". Some people think they're much more perceptive than they really are, others don't trust themselves as much as they should!

Answer (score 1):

It is colloquial.

"To suck at..." means to be very bad at doing something.

> I suck at maths.  I can't even remember my times tables.

"smarts" means intelligence or natural ability

> He has the smarts to be a doctor.

Put together, it means that we are bad at judging our own skills and intelligence.

This is a common observation: People who are very able at something are more aware of their mistakes and so judge themselves to be weak.  People who are not able, are not aware of their weaknesses, and so think that they are better than they are.